# Javascript での多次元配列の初期化について

Tags: javascript

これだとダメで

```
var histArray = new Array(256);
var histData = [histArray,histArray,histArray];
for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < 256; j++){
        histData[i][j] = 0;
    }
}
```

こっちだとちゃんと初期化されるんですが、これはなぜでしょうか？

```
var histData = [histArray,histArray,histArray];
for(j = 0; j < 3; j++){
    histData[j] = new Array(256);
    for(i = 0; i < 256; i++){
        histData[j][i] = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: OK, NG のコード例は逆ではないですか？

Answer (score 8):

> var histData = [histArray,histArray,histArray];

histArray のインスタンス(実体)はただ一つですので、これでは常に

```
histData[0][n] == histData[1][n] == histData[2][n] == histArray[n]
```

となってしまいます。例えば histData[0][1] に値を代入すると、histData[1][1] と histData[2]
[1] と histArray[1] もその値と同じになってしまいます(全て同じインスタンスを指しているからです)。

ですので、以下の様にして初期化する必要があります。

```
var histData = [new Array(256), new Array(256), new Array(256)];
```

Answer (score 3):

1つめのコード例では `histData[0]`, `histData[1]`, `histData[2]` がすべて同じ入れ物を指しています。したがって、1つめのコード例で初期化した `histData[n][m]` を使おうとするとおかしなことになります。

2つめのコード例では3行目の `new Array(256)` で新しい入れ物を用意していますので `histData[0]`, `histData[1]`, `histData[2]` はすべて別々の入れ物を指すことになります。なので、思ったように使えるようになります。

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript 1.7 なら配列内包っていう便利なのがあるんだけどね

```
function range(begin, end) {
  for (let i = begin; i < end; i++) {
    yield i;
  }
}

var histData = [[0 for each(j in range(0, 256))] for each(i in range(0, 3))];
```